# Woocommerce External /Affiliate Product along with downloadable type?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Can some one give idea how to achieve the following:
My Wordpress with woocommerce has downloadable books as pdf files. These books are sold as paperback on Amazon.
Now I want to allow users to download and also show a "Buy Paperback" (or what ever button text) along with the download links
How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way was to use a plugin Forget about Short Code buttons by Design & Code.
No shortcode to paste. We can have custom urls defined for each button we create in each post